# Rel attribute not working from a mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a series of images displayed on a page.  They are being called from a mysql database. This part works fine.  I then implemented a hover image with description using the following code:

```
...echo "<td>";?> <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" rel="imgtip[0]" height="100" width="125" title="<?php echo $row['title_tag']; ?>" /><?php echo "</td>";...
```

The **rel="imgtip[0]"** is the part that calls the hover image and description.  This will only call the first image identified as '0'. I want it to change to **rel="imgtip[1]"**, **rel="imtip[2]**" etc. so each hover image will relate to the one being called from the database.

I added a new field to the mysql database and added each **rel** as a new record.  I then changed the php code to call the rel attribute from the database as follows:

```
...echo "<td>";?> <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" height="100" width="125" title="<?php echo $row['title_tag']; ?>" rel="<?php echo $row['img_tip'] ?>"  /><?php echo "</td>";...
```

This time when I viewed the page no hover image appeared.  Is there some way to call the rel attribute from the database so it will display the required hover images?

Comment: You're not calling the `rel` attribute from the database. You're retrieving a field from the database as text, and then just echoing it amongst other HTML content... Are you sure that `img_tip` is the name of the field? What happens if you write `print_r($row)`? Do you see the array key `img_tip` with a value?

Comment: When I do try the print_r($row) I get the following example code for one of the images: [4] => rel="imgtip[2]"
    [img_tip] => rel="imgtip[2]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, it looks like the MySQL field `img_tip` contains the definition for `rel=` already. If that's the case, update your code as follows:

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" height="100" width="125" title="<?php echo $row['title_tag']; ?>" <?php echo $row['img_tip'] ?> />
```

Comment: Excellent...it worked.  Thanks for your help BenM, that would have taken me a while.